# Problem with mini-cart ajax not displayed

Tags: ajax, header, mini-cart

yesterday i make an update to ajax-cart.

With no reason, now, there is no mini-cart been displayed.

As normally, i have this ok `header.phtml`

```
<div class="nav-right span3">
                <div class="header-right-inner">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mini-cart') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The module is already installed and configurated.

Any idea or what i could do to check what is going bad?

As i see on output, anything is been printed by the child mini-cart.

The layout is fine too.

Here is the code of `mini-cart.phtml`

```
<div class="block mini-cart sns-ajaxcart<?php echo ($_cartQty > 0)?' have-item':''; ?>">
    <div class="block-title">
        <?php if(count($_items)){ ?>
        <?php /*<strong><span><?php echo $this->__('My Cart') ?></span></strong>*/?>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ico-view"></a>
            <?php if ($_cartQty>0){ ?>
            <div class="cart-status">
                <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('My Cart') ?></span>
                <span class="subtotal">
                    <?php if ($this->canApplyMsrp()): ?>
                        <span class="map-cart-sidebar-total"><?php echo $this->__('ORDER TOTAL WILL BE DISPLAYED BEFORE YOU SUBMIT THE ORDER'); ?></span>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <span class="amount"><?php echo $this->__('%s', $_cartQty) ?></span>
                        <span><?php echo $this->__('item(s) - '); ?></span>
                        <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal()) ?>
                        <?php if ($_subtotalInclTax = $this->getSubtotalInclTax()): ?>
                            <br />(<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_subtotalInclTax) ?> <?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->getIncExcText(true) ?>)
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </span>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php }else { ?>
                <div class="cart-status">
                <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('My Cart') ?></span>
                <span class="subtotal">
                    <span>0 <?php echo $this->__('item(s) - '); ?></span>
                    <span><?php echo $this->__('0.00') ?></span>
                </span>
               </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php if ($_cartQty>0){ ?>
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="block-inner">
            <?php if($_cartQty && ($this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout() OR $this->getQuote()->getHasError())): ?>
            <?php endif ?>
            <?php if(count($_items)){?>
                <p class="block-subtitle">
                    <?php
                    if($config['list_type']=='all'){
                    echo $this->__('All added item(s)');
                    }else{
                    echo $this->__('Recently added item(s)');
                    }
                    ?>
                </p>
                <?php
                $aPost  = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost(); //Zend_Debug::dump($aPost);
                ?>
                <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post" id="minicart-form<?php echo $uq ?>">
                    <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo ($aPost['form_key']!='')?$aPost['form_key']:Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
                    <ol id="minicart-sidebar" class="mini-products-list">
                    <?php foreach($_items as $_item): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ol>
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('minicart-sidebar', 'none-recursive')</script>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="bottom-action actions">
                <?php if($_cartQty && ($this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout() OR $this->getQuote()->getHasError())){ ?>
                    <button data-original-title="<?php echo $this->__('Go to cart') ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Go to cart') ?>" class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/') ?>')"><?php echo $this->__('Go to cart') ?></button>
                    <button data-original-title="<?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?>" class="button btn-gocheckout" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>')"><?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?></button>
                <?php  } ?>
                <button data-original-title="<?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart'); ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" name="update_cart_action" value="update_qty" onclick="minicart.callAction();"title="<?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart'); ?>" class="button btn-update"><?php echo $this->__('Update'); ?></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: you edit the rwd theme mini cart?

Comment: Nope @QaisarSatti .
My url for my templates are:
`app\design\frontend\default\sns_nova\template`

Comment: you are adding you own js?

Comment: @QaisarSatti no, i use the javascript in view.phtml.
I edit to show it.

Comment: this javascript code is for submitting the form in view phtml

Comment: Which JS you want then? 
On mini-cart.phtml there is only a line:
`If(!IS_HANDHELD){
}else{
jQuery('.mini-cart').addClass('handeld');
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24493/discussion-between-ntzz-and-qaisar-satti).